# "Ein Küsschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren"? Proverb or sarcasm?

Tags: meaning, usage, proverb

When someone would say:

> Ein Küsschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren.

"No one can deny a light kiss in honorific way" — is that its exact definition?
Is it sarcasm? When would someone usually say it?

Comment: Nobody would say this nowadays. It is understood as sexism. There is an other more common similar: Ein Gläschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren.

Comment: Oh! thanks @Thomas ! so it has been abolished! good to know and not use it in my text messages.

Comment: I first thought was: "Ferrero Küsschen" has a new advertisment. Their advertisment slogan is "Guten Freunden gibt man ein Küsschen"

Comment: Thanks @Iris! do you know whether the mentioned proverb is abolished now or not?

Comment: @Armin, "Guten Freunden gibt man ein Küsschen" is the most famous  slogan of Ferrero Küsschen and they still use it (see https://www.ferrero-kuesschen.de/).

Comment: @Thomas As with all things that may be sexist, it depends who you’re saying it to. (And, as Iris mentioned, whether the chocolate is meant or an actual kiss.) I wouldn’t call it ‘abolished’.

Comment: Thanks dear @Iris to know this slogan as well in addition to my question, but from ""mentioned" I meant my sentence mentioned above. anyway sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @Armin, no, "Ein Küsschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren." is not and never was a slogan of Ferrero Küsschen. It just sounds like it and is sometimes used by costumers in reviews about the product.

Comment: dear @Iris! I didn't mean ""Ein Küsschen in Ehren kann niemand verwehren." (my sentence mentioned above) was a slogan o Ferrero Küsschen! I meant thank you to know your new sentence and its usage as slogan o Ferrero Küsschen in addition to my question. (I Think tonight we all need to let our brain a little sleep ;) anyway, by me, it's 11:15 and goodnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitively not sarcastic, it is more a humorous proverb that is said to come from the 17th century as you can read [in this link (german)](http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/232130/Ein_K%C3%BCsschen_in_Ehren_kann_niemand_verwehren).

The translation is: a light kiss can / should not be denied.

It is said with a twinkle in your eye that says: Come on, who can say no to a "little" kiss...

Comment: *Should* or *could*. You can be both the offering and the receiving party imho.